# Looping through textFields in a Nativescript view

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I would like to loop through all the textFields in a view. I know I can get a single field the following way:

```
exports.loaded = function (args) {
  var layout = args.object;
  fnameInput = layout.getViewById("fname-input");
}
```

It doesn't seem that there is a getViewsByClassName method, and I'm not finding anything in the docs that point me to a method which returns an array of views or elements within a view. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Nathanael Anderson’s [nativescript-dom plugin](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-dom), as it has a `getElementsByClassName()` function that seems to be what you’re looking for here.

If you don’t want to incur the dependency of the full plugin, you can refer to [Nathanael’s implementation of that method](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-dom/blob/3a45c447d88e144649fa517545cd6db5be310ea2/dom.js#L289-L331) to get an idea of how to use the View class APIs to get at the elements you need. Specifically, note the [`eachDescendant()` method](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_core_view_.html#eachdescendant) that all Views have, as you’ll need to use that to walk the NativeScript user interface tree.